# Spring Data Elasticsearch nested field multimatch query

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch with spring-data-elastic. And try to use multi search. The problem is while search wprking with class fields, its not working with nested fields. My mapping is like below

```
{
    "archieve": {
        "mappings": {
            "author": {
                "properties": {
                    "books": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "standard"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "firstName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    },
                    "lastName": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have an endpoint with searchQuery like:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/es/archieve/multi/{keyword}")
  public Page<Author> getBrandMulti(@PathVariable String keyword, Pageable pageable) {

      SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
                      .withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(keyword)
                              .field("firstName", 1.2f)
                              .field("books.name", 1.1f)
                              .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.CROSS_FIELDS)
                              .fuzziness(Fuzziness.TWO)
                      )
                      .withIndices("archieve")
                      .withTypes("author")
                      .withPageable(pageable)
                      .build();

      return elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, Author.class);
  }
```

The problem is query is not working for ***nested field***. Is there any suggestion, regards?

**Update**

In fact nested objects can be queried as

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(QueryBuilders.nestedQuery("books", 
         QueryBuilders.termQuery("books.name", searchKey)))
```

Is there anyway to concat two queries like

```
NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
    .withQuery(Query1)
    .withQuery(Query1)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ES Nested Objects

As [the document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html) says, when you query a nested field, you have to use nested query:

> Because nested objects are indexed as separate hidden documents, we can’t query them directly. Instead, we have to use the nested query to access them:

#### Spring Data

Back to the spring data, I prefer the way using `Query`, which IMO, more readable:

```java
@Query(" {" +
        " \"bool\": {\n" +
        "     \"should\": [\n" +
        "       {\n" +
        "         \"multi_match\": {\n" +
        "           \"query\": \"?0\",\n" +
        "           \"fields\": [\"firstName\"]\n" +
        "         }\n" +
        "       },\n" +
        "       {\n" +
        "         \"nested\": {\n" +
        "           \"path\": \"books\",\n" +
        "           \"query\": {\n" +
        "             \"match\": {\n" +
        "               \"books.name\": \"?0\"\n" +
        "             }}\n" +
        "         }\n" +
        "       } ]\n" +
        "  }" +
        "}")
Page<EsBrand> findByNameOrBooks(String info, Pageable pageable);
```

You can put this signature in your repo interface, which spring will implement a proxy to do the other jobs.